# XNA 2D objects in 3D environment

Tags: 3d, xna-4.0

I'm currently working on a 3D game in XNA 4.0 and I have a 3D environment, a controllable character and a camera that follows the character up and running. But now I would like to draw 2D images in the 3D environment.
The reason for 2D images is that I want Legend of Zelda Windwaker like explosions.

Can anyone give me recourses, advice or code snippets (in case it's really simple) on how to build this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect you are trying to achieve is called **billboarding**. A quad is placed into 3D space and rotated in a way so that it always faces the camera (spherical billboarding). Billboards can also be restricted to rotate around a single axis (cylindrical billboarding).

- [HLSL Cylindrical Billboarding (for XNA)](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Billboarding.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MAtrix.CreateBillboard-Method to rotate a plane coorectly:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.createbillboard(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx